# Sometimes plugin app controller is not found

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.x

Sometimes Im get this kind of error when working with my plugins:

```
Class PluginNameAppController not found in ...
```

It's really weird because I connect plugin AppController before any controller using App::uses();

And this error occur randomly, then, I refresh current page (or clean tmp\cache\persistent) and it's gone.

I have 3 plugins connected in Config/bootstrap.php and I think they are conflicting some how.

Cakephp 2.6.0.

Comment: We need more information about this error, else we won't be able to give a solution ;)

Comment: I really dont know what to add. It's all data that I have. What do you want to know?

Comment: I want the full error-stack of the error. Only telling sometimes you get 'an' error, nobody can help you with that

Comment: Here is full error text (provided by CakePHP) and plugin controller code: http://chopapp.com/#65z1er7l

Comment: What are your plugins ?

Comment: @Abhishek it's admin plugins with different zones.

Comment: can you share list of all plugins you are using except the admin one if any ?

Comment: @Abhishek here bootstrap.php plugins load code: http://chopapp.com/#ac3bwni7

Comment: Are you using any caching ?

Comment: @Abhishek I'm using file caching engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem is still not resolved, but here is few solutions to resolve it:

1. Comment this lines in core.php: [chopapp.com/#i5x18g0p](http://chopapp.com/#i5x18g0p)
2. Uncomment `Cache.disable` in core.php: `Configure::write('Cache.disable', true);`

Answer (score 0):

Use

`Configure::write('Cache.viewPrefix', 'prefix');`

with different value
in PluginAppController's beforeFilter function.

Comment: Nope, did't work. Actually it's problem with "persistent" folder cache files not with "view" folder. I have found two solutions to resolve problem: 
1. Comment this lines in core.php - http://chopapp.com/#i5x18g0p
2. Uncomment Cache.disable in core.php  
`Configure::write('Cache.disable', true);`